# How do I add images inside my JavaScript to display Pause and Play icons?

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to use two images to act as play and pause buttons for my tutorial script.  How do I replace the "Start" and "Stop" inside my JavaScript with two images instead?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').css('visibility','visible').hide(),
        dur = 100;

    function showDiv() {
        $("div.fader").fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 4 * 1000); // do this every 7 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
});
```

and here is my Fiddle: [Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/NpNXr/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the text value of the element, change the CSS class name. Have two different classes, each using a background image.

Comment: so my script would look like, 

$("#start").click(function(){
  if (interval == undefined){
  interval = fadeLoop();
  $(this).val(".imageClassStop");
  }
  else {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $(this).val(".imageClassStart");.....??

Comment: $(this).addClass("imageClassStop") - or - $(this).removeClass("imageClassStop")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a button, just set the onclick event for an image in your markup.  Then you could modify the image with the attr JQuery function:

```
$(this).attr('src', '[path to my image]');
```

I couldn't get your JSFiddle to load, but seeing some markup would probably be helpful.

Edit:

I checked back again, and the JSFiddle seems to be up now.  The input at the bottom of your markup should either be a div or an img tag.  If you use an img tag, use the code above to modify the source image on the click event.

A div might be better since you can preload the background images.  In the case of a div you can set the background image with two CSS classes:

```
.start {
    background-image: url('start.png');
}

.stop{
    background-image: url('stop.png');
}
```

Then you need to remove the start class and add the stop class or vice versa:

```
$(this).removeClass('start');
$(this).addClass('stop');
```

If you modify the CSS stop selector and make it ".start.stop" you can even just remove and add the stop class instead of having to worry about removing and adding the start class as well.